# How to travel across South America?

Tags: argentina, peru, south-america, colombia

As I know, there are no low cost airlines in South America. In Europe or in Asia you fly to another country for relatively low price.

- What's the most convenient/cheapest options to travel between South America countries?
- Do I need to book them in advance?

Comment: I think you need to choose, either concenient or cheap. There are other question on the site on this topic. Try to search for "travel south america".

Comment: Recently a few low cost airlines popped up in Argentina, and likely around other countries too. FlyBondi is the one I remember, but I think there's others. The most common other mean of transportation is probably taking a bus, and you probably shouldn't worry too much about booking in advance. My experience is mostly in Argentina, though, so take that with a grain of salt. For instance, (multiple) buses between Rosario and Buenos Aires depart every 30 mins, and there's been room in the next one every time I've been to the terminal.

Comment: not sure how you define 'low-cost airline' - you can often fly for 30-80$ in South America. Seems 'low-cost' to me.

Comment: @Aganju yes, it's low. Maybe I didn't investigate enough. It's too broad question, I'll close it.